# Importing a JSX file in another JSX file

Tags: reactjs, import

I'm a very beginner in React. I created a general React Component in a JSX file and then I intend to import it in another JSX file. However, when I import the following error is returned `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

This is my general object:

```
class Footer extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>Footer</div>
        );
    }
}
export default Footer;
```

And this is the other JSX file:

```
import Footer from './generalPageFooter.jsx';
const contentNode = document.getElementById('div-content');
class AdminPanel extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Sample Text</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class AdminPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Sample Text</h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<AdminPage />, contentNode);
```

In the HTML file the code is the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="div-content">
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/adminPage.jsx"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the line where the error is happening? Is it in the code included?

Comment: Regardless, if you are using require somewhere in one of your files, that may be the problem. If you are using ES6, just use import.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly run ES6/JSX on the browser. They need to be transpiled to "pure" JS then browser can understand and execute them.

Take a look on [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

P/S: If you are starting with React, I suggest [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) from Facebook.

Comment: Plus take a look on 'webpack' using Babel format, this tool is god to react users.